# JSON does not parse to arraylist in Android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am using volley for the first time and my JSON response will not parse to my arraylist. Everything looks right to me.

This is how the arraylist has been declared.

```
 ArrayList<TrigNumbersModel> numbersList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is the method that gets the JSON:

```
 public  void fetchJson(final String subID){
    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(TrigNumbers.this);

    StringRequest myRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URL_STRING + "?sub_id=" + subID,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        numbersList.clear();
                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            outter(jo.toString());
                            TrigNumbersModel trigNumbersModel = new TrigNumbersModel();
                            trigNumbersModel.setTrigNo(jo.getString("phone"));
                            outter(jo.getString("phone"));
                            numbersList.add(trigNumbersModel);

                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    outter("" + error);


                }
            }) ;
    requestQueue.add(myRequest);
}
```

And this is my object class

```
public class TrigNumbersModel {

@SerializedName("triggerNumber")
String trigNo;

public TrigNumbersModel(String trigNo) {
    this.trigNo = trigNo;

}

public TrigNumbersModel() {
}

public String getTrigNo() {
    return trigNo;

}

public void setTrigNo(String trigNo) {
    this.trigNo = trigNo;
}

}
```

This is my JSON format

```
[{"id":"4866","phone":"233243602185","subscription_id":"HJ5559","cutomer_id":"20"}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: we'd need to see your json format to help you

Comment: Do not create adapter inside loop .

Comment: question has been edited

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)  convert json to corresponding list of objects.

```
TypeToken<List<TrigNumbersModel>> token = new TypeToken<List<TrigNumbersModel>>() {};
List<TrigNumbersModel> animals = gson.fromJson(data, token.getType());
```

And this is your model class.

```
public class TrigNumbersModel {

private String id;
private String phone;
private String subscriptionId;
private String cutomerId;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getPhone() {
return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
this.phone = phone;
}

public String getSubscriptionId() {
return subscriptionId;
}

public void setSubscriptionId(String subscriptionId) {
this.subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
}

public String getCutomerId() {
return cutomerId;
}

public void setCutomerId(String cutomerId) {
this.cutomerId = cutomerId;
}

}
```

and in your app level `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
}
```